# Не работает свойство background

Tags: html, css

Хочу ставить в css свойство background на типа слайдер,в нем находится лого и меню, а если просто-хедер. Вставил все div-ы в div слайдер,выставил пока для него размеры 200x200 но чет не работает у меня это,в чем проблема может быть?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="slider">
     <div class="header">
     <div class="logo">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.jpg">
</div>
<div class="menu">
Home
About Us
Portfolio
Features
Blog
Pricing
Shortcodes
Contact
</div>
<div class="card-header">
<img src="images/header-card.jpg">
</div>
<div class="search-header">
<img src="images/icon-search.jpg">
</div>
     </div>
        </div>

    </body>    
</html>
```

сss файл:

```
.header{
display:inline-block;
}
.slider{
background-image: url('images/slider-bg.jpg');;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: что не работает? из вопроса ничего не понятно. если картинка не показывается, то надо проверить путь. возможно, надо указать вот так: `background-image: url('../images/slider-bg.jpg')`

Comment: проблема в пути к изображению, либо в свойствах более приоритетного правила для указанного блока, либо в том, что ваш фон полностью закрывается внутренними элементами. По вашему описанию проблемы гадать можно бесконечно

Answer (score 2):

Если ошибка в ; не считается, то посмотри на путь изображения , если оно находится в рядом находящейся папке, то путь `background-image: url('../images/slider-bg.jpg');` иначе ошибка только в написании лишнего знака или отсутствии изображения.

Answer (score 1):

лишняя точка с запятой в background image